# WxPthon Question: Subpanels within a Notebook Panel

Tags: python, wxpython, matplotlib, panel

I am currently a summer research student helping out with computational biology research, and my role is to make a GUI that visualizes data. At the moment, I am using wxPython and matplotlib. I have two panels set up within a notebook - the first panel is the options and the second panel is where the visualization will be. However, in addition I would like the second panel to contain four subpanels within it--so it has a graph in each subpanel. Though, when I try to add subpanels to my secondpanel, they don't seem to show up. Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Here is what my goal is - at the moment the Visualization panel is blank:
[image: My Ideal Program]

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/834/cuffvis2ideal.jpg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't see any point in creating a panel on top of the tab's panel. That's redundant. You can just use the tab's panel as the top panel and eliminate selfPanel. Then you can just create 4 other panels with a parent of "self" (i.e. the tab itself).

You'll need 3 BoxSizers or 1 GridSizer. I personally like the flexibility of using the BoxSizers, but that's up to you. Put the panels in the sizers and set them to EXPAND and give them a proportion of 1. Something like:

myBoxSizer.Add(panelOne, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)

That should work.